# Defining an new itemize like environment where \item[foo] passes foo to a macro

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

I want to use `enumitem` or similar package to define a basic list with the following properties:

1. When `\item` has no optional argument, a small square (`\rule{1em}{1em}`) is used
2. When `\item[foo]` is called, the itemize icon is `\mymacro{foo}`

I would actually settle for `\item` with no argument defaulting to `\mymacro{somedefaultvalue}` so I could then conditional-fu my way round that issue...

The background is I am making a list where the items are more or less complete, and would like little pie charts to indicate how complete the various things are. The pie charts I've made in TikZ, but I don't know how to get them where I want them, apart from calling them explicitly. (I'm writing a thesis outline, with indications of which parts need work and which parts are finished. Or rather, I'm procrastinating by playing with TikZ...)

This is what it looks like currently, but I have to call `\mymacro` explicitly in each `\item` There's all sorts of other minor things that need fixing, like aligning the centre of the circle with the centre line of the text and so on...

[image: pie chart]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{seamusitemize}
  {\itemize\let\origitem\item
   \renewcommand{\item}[1][default]
   {\origitem[\csname seamus##1\endcsname]}}
  {\enditemize}

\newcommand{\seamusdefault}{\textbullet}
\newcommand{\seamusx}{x}
\newcommand{\seamusy}{y}

\begin{document}
\begin{seamusitemize}
\item pippo
\item[x] pluto
\item[y] paperino
\end{seamusitemize}
\end{document}
```

In this way you needn't know how `\makelabel` is defined in `itemize`; you can use enumitem to adapt the parameters for the space reserved to the label.

If the definition of the commands `\seamus...` is not feasible, you can change `\csname seamus##1\endcsname` into `\mymacro{##1}`. It's easy to define `\mymacro` to do a default when its argument is `default`:

```
\def\seamusdefault{default}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
   \def\next{#1}%
   \ifx\next\seamusdefault
      <default code>%
   \else
      <code using #1>%
   \fi}
```

*Comments*
As Danie Els observed, it's a bit dangerous to redefine `\item`; no list environment or other environments that depend on these, such as `center` or `flushleft` must not be nested in `seamusitemize`. A safer strategy would be to redefine `\makelabel`:

```
\newenvironment{seamusitemize}
  {\itemize[label=default]               
   \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
   \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\origmakelabel{\mymacro{##1}}}}
  {\enditemize}
```

Then `\mymacro` can do what's required, as explained above. This *requires* to load **enumitem** (thanks to Seamus for pointing it out).

Comment: @egreg this relies on defining `\seamusx` and friends beforehand: I would like to allow the optional arguments to be at least any number between 0 and 100. I don't want to define 101 macros (leaving aside the issues with macros not being able to have numbers in). I want the option to be passed as an _argument_ to the macro...)

Comment: @Seamus You're allowed to do what you want with that argument: say `\mymacro{##1}` instead of `\csname seamus##1\endcsname`.

Comment: Ah I see. and then I'd need to change `\mymacro{default}` to give me my default behaviour?

Comment: This is basically the solution I opted for, but I defined `\mymacro` with `xparse` because I find its handling of defaults and so on easier to understand.

Comment: @egreg: @Seamus: NEVER EVER redefine `\item`. A lot of internal latex macros depend on it! For example put a `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}`  environment inside `seamusitemize` and see what happens.

Comment: @Danie I don't see the problem? the text in the `center` environment gets centered. It looks silly, but that's what I expected it to do... The redefinition is just a wrapper for the original definition, and it's local to the environment, so I don't see how it can cause serious problems

Comment: @Seamus: The `center`, `quote`, `flushleft`, `flushright`, `verse` and some others all have internaly a `\item[]` command. If you use them inside an environment where `\item` was redefined you end up with a bullet and bad spacing. I often use quote inside lists to emphasis a paragraph.

Comment: @Danie I see. I take the point, but as long as I don't use those environments and the change is local, then there's no problem.

Comment: @Danie You're right, talking in general. I'll add something about this in my answer.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that your second example (the redefining `\makelabel` one) needs `enumitem`...

Answer (score 12):

The `itemize` labels are typest using the `\makelabel` macro which receives the optional argument of `\item` as mandatory argument. The default argument is `\@itemlabel` which is defined to `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii` etc. depending on the level.

You could simply define an own `itemize` environment which sets this macros accordantly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mydefaultlabel}{%
    \@gobble{mydefaultlabel}% unique definition
}

\newcommand{\mymakelabel}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \def\@tempb{\@itemlabel}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \endgroup
        \hss \llap{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}%
    \else
    \endgroup
        \hss \llap{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,rotate=90]
          \path (0,0) circle (.5em);
          \fill [blue] (0,0) -- +(0:.5em)
          arc [start angle=0, delta angle={(#1)*3.6}, radius=.5em] -- cycle; %
    \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    \fi
}

\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \itemize
    \let\makelabel\mymakelabel
    \let\@itemlabel\mydefaultlabel
}{%
    \enditemize
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
    \item test
    \item[10] a
    \item[80] b
    \item[50] c
    \item[100] c
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I much prefer that more verbose description of arcs. I find the `(0:30:1)` syntax very difficult to read. This has the drawback/feature (depending on perspective) that you need to do it for each level of itemization...

Comment: @Seamus: It took me a while to get so far. The whole `arc` syntax is quite strange for me. Also I always have to remember which value comes first in polar coordinates, the angle or the radius. The `(angle:radius)` syntax is counter-intuitive for me I would find `(radius:angle)` would make more sense.

Comment: @Martin no I think that way round makes sense, first you pick your direction, then you work out how far along that direction to walk...

Comment: @Seamus: Ok, this makes sense. I have to remember that. What is with the `(0:30:1)` syntax you mentioned? I never heard about it.

Comment: That's the short syntax for defining arcs. I don't like it: I prefer the long form. With the short one, the first two numbers are the start and end angles for the arc and the third number is the radius of the circle...

Comment: @Seamus: I found it now in the manual. Sometimes it is a little confusing. If you search of `arc` in the PDF and follow the found link in the TOC you find the short version first (I think as part of the tutorial), but if you search in the index and follow the entry there you find the long form. There is only a small note about the short form which I overlooked.

Answer (score 6):

I would keep it as simple as possible by not redefining anything and make a special item command. Unfortunately I do not know TikZ and have therefore used a partially filled box to illustrate the concept.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\mybullet[1]{{%
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1em}%
          \rule{1em}{#1em}}}}

\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bitem[1][]{%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{\item[$\bullet$]}%--> or anything else e,g. \mybullet{0}
                 {\item[\mybullet{#1}]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[]
    \bitem       aaaa
    \bitem[0.25] bbbb
    \bitem[0.00] ccc
    \bitem[1.00] yyyy
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This will give something like the following

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it relies on the fact that if the `#1` isn't there it is ignored, and the macro code works whether or not there is something in that place. I'd rather have the "default" code handled differently. How might this be modified to have the default `\item` be an empty square rather than a full one?

Comment: @Seamus: I have changed the default optional argument of `\bitem` to 0, but note that it is opposite to your original request.

Comment: @Danie I know: I'm not sure what I want to do with the default yet, but I think I'd rather be able to execute arbitrary different code for the default case...

Comment: @Seamus: I understand. See the change to code for `\bitem`.

Comment: It is better in general to do `\ifx\empty#1` than `\ifx#1\empty`: try with `#1` equal to `00.1` for instance.

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch: You are so right. Look at the following discussion on [CTT](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/3e454491396249b6/5d665049a5274089?#5d665049a5274089). I tend to forget these things ;-)